# Drupal 7 multi site site specific theme is not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, open-source, multisite

I have created a multi site on Drupal 7. I have mapped it with two different domain namely tom.mydomain.com and jerry.mydomain.com.

Accordingly I have created two separate database namely tomdb and jerrydb and created a respective directory (folders) under the sites directory.

My Current folder structures are mentioned below

drupal/sites/all
drupal/sites/default
drupal/sites/tom.mydomain.com
drupal/sites/jerry.mydomain.com

I have changed the database connection details in the settings.php under the specific folders.

Everything works fine till now.

However, I wanted to use site specific theme and logo for both domain. So I created a theme folders under particular directory. But drupal is not considering the correct theme specific to that particular site. It is everywhere still using the theme from site/all folders.

Would you please suggest why it is not using theme i have created for particular domain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After you add a multi-site theme under the specific site's directory, for example, `drupal/sites/tom.mydomain.com/themes/tom_theme`, you need to set that theme as the default theme for your particular site.

This is done in the Admin area under Appearance. See detailed instructions here http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/customize-theme/change-default-theme

Also just checking you have configured the `sites/sites.php` file, which maps domains to the particular multisites. 
See details here https://www.webwash.net/drupals-multi-site-aliasing-with-sites-php/